# How do I make both buttons different colors

Tags: html, css, button, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want too make both buttons a different collor

```
<header class="masthead">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">
          <div class="intro-lead-in">Jeroen Hooge schilderwerken</div>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Prijs</a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Werkzaamheden</a>
        </div>
      </div>
</header>
```

this is the code I use, But if I change the color both buttons will change and not 1.

[What it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqUCs.png)

[what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiQfO.png)

Comment: how about reasearching on your own at all besfore you ask something??? just use an extra class for the color...

Comment: That's litterally some basic knowledge everyone working with css should have. Add a class, let's say "brown" to one of your buttons. Then style the class brown like this: ".brown { background: brown }

Comment: I agree with both of you guys, but I posted an answer anyway.
It could be nice to have the CSS code in your question, too, @youarewelcomeee !

Answer (score 1):

You can inline style for change background for the particular button

```css
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    line-height: inherit;
    border-radius: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: auto;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.btn-primary.active.focus, .btn-primary.active:focus, .btn-primary.active:hover, .btn-primary:active.focus, .btn-primary:active:focus, .btn-primary:active:hover, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary.focus, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:focus, .open>.dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #204d74;
    border-color: #122b40;
}

.btn-primary{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #286090;
    padding: 10px; 5px;
}
```

```html
<header class="masthead">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">
          <div class="intro-lead-in">Jeroen Hooge schilderwerken</div>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Prijs</a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase js-scroll-trigger" style="background:#ccc;"href="#services">Werkzaamheden</a>
        </div>
      </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ***:nth-of-type(2)*** to select the second btn and you can change any css property you want.

```css
.intro-text .btn {
  background: #333;
}

.intro-text .btn:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="masthead">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">
          <div class="intro-lead-in">Jeroen Hooge schilderwerken</div>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Prijs</a>
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Werkzaamheden</a>
        </div>
      </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I think that `:nth-of-type(2)` is too complicated for someone who is asking that kind of question. But, yea. :)

Comment: May be it is complicated, but definitely better than inline styles or adding one more class name. :)

Answer (score 0):

simply give an ID to  tag so that it can be identified uniquely

```css
#black{
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}

#brown {
  background-color: brown;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
  <header class="masthead">
 <div class="container">
<div class="intro-text">
      <div class="intro-lead-in">Jeroen Hooge schilderwerken</div>
      <a id="black" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Prijs</a>
      <a id="brown" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Werkzaamheden</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
`
```

Answer (score -1):

Add to classes. One general for all the `a` tags. And one for the `:first-of-type`

```css
.intro-text a:first-of-type{
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

.intro-text a {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<header class="masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="intro-text">
      <div class="intro-lead-in">Jeroen Hooge schilderwerken</div>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Prijs</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xl text-uppercase js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Werkzaamheden</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use those classes available in [Bootstrap buttons](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#buttons-options) as example below or create your own classes.

```
<header class="masthead">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="intro-text">
          <div class="intro-lead-in">Jeroen Hooge schilderwerken</div>
          <a class="btn btn-default btn-xl text-uppercase js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Prijs</a>
          <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xl text-uppercase js-scroll-trigger" href="#services">Werkzaamheden</a>
        </div>
      </div>
</header>
```